# How do I compare to ranges of data with duplicates and see if the duplicate values are equal

Tags: excel

So in this example I have a student that has changed some classes around and has gotten new grades. I want to compare the classes they kept on and see which grades has changed since. I can match duplicates but because the old classes are not in the same order as the new classes I can't compare the grades.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `vlookup`?

Comment: @findwindow I've used it to search for the duplicate classes but I'm not sure how I can link the duplicate classes to their new grades

Comment: Try reading the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) again?